# Understanding const reference returned from a function

Tags: c++

I have a function

```
const std::string& getRecordingJobToken() { return getToken(); }
const std::string& getToken() const { return m_Token;  }
std::string m_Token;
```

I am able to call it as below

```
const std::string jobToken = getRecordingJobToken();
```

However when I do this,

```
const std::string jobToken;
jobToken = getRecordingJobToken();
```

It throws me this error -

error: passing ‘const string’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string’} as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

What is the difference ?
I know that a reference variable has to be initialized immediately.

std::string &ref = a;

Is it some similiar logic ? The reason i am confused is that though getRecordingJobToken() returns a const reference, the variable jobToken that I have is not a reference variable. It is a variable that is used to take a string reference being returned from the getRecordingJobToken() function.

Comment: "_It is a variable that is used to take a string reference_": Maybe you have some misunderstanding here: `jobToken` doesn't "_take_" a reference, it is itself an independent string object and initialization or assingment copy the referenced string's contents into `jobToken`. So the assignment requires modifying `jobToken`'s contents, which is exactly what `const` is supposed to prevent. The `const` on `jobToken` is completely independent of the `const` on the returned reference.

Comment: You're confusing the assignment operator with the symbol `=` which occurs in one form of copy-initialization syntax.   These two different usages of the same symbol have no relation to each other in C++, you could pretend that different symbols were used if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization and assignment are different things. `jobToken` is `const`, it could be initialized, e.g.

```
const std::string jobToken = getRecordingJobToken(); // copy-initialization
```

but can't be assigned (modified) later, e.g.

```
const std::string jobToken;        // default-initialization
jobToken = getRecordingJobToken(); // fails; assignment
```

Comment: The string doesn't have to be initialized - you can omit initializer to get an empty const string.

Answer (score 1):

> I am able to call it as below
>
> ```cpp
> const std::string jobToken = getRecordingJobToken();
> ```
>
> However when I do this,
>
> ```cpp
> const std::string jobToken;
> jobToken = getRecordingJobToken();
> ```
>
> error ...

Yes, you can initialize a `const` object (which is what you do in the first example), but you can't assign to it/change it afterwards (which is what you try doing in the second example).

Note that you don't have to though. The function `getRecordingJobToken()` returns a `const std::string&` which is "cheap" with regards to resources. It's just a refrence to an internal `std::string` that the `class` or function keeps - but doesn't let anyone modify from the outside. If you only need to *read* the value, take it by `const` reference instead:

```
const std::string& jobToken = getRecordingJobToken();
```

If you on the other hand would like to modify the returned value, take it by value (and get a copy of whatever is returned). Your `jobToken` does not need to be `const` in this situation:

```
std::string jobToken = getRecordingJobToken();
jobToken += "foo"; // ok now since it's not `const`
```